# How to pass arguments to call a shell script from tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess

I want to execute a shell script with arguments from a tkinter gui. I have written the code for text box for user input and when the button is pressed, it executes the script and as a test prints the text box value as well.

However, I want the text box values to be passed to the shell script when I press the button. How do I make this call? please help.

The code below was put together from various code samples I gathered from this website.. Thanks to all who provided this....

The problem line is this...`Date.sh` should take inputvalue as a parameter...
`Date.sh` just prints date... nothing fancy here...

```
subprocess.call(['./date.sh inputValue']) #shell=True)
```

I am running this in python3

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

root=Tk()

#subprocess.call(['./verify_script.sh', var.get()])
def retrieve_input():
    inputValue=textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    print(inputValue)

textBox=Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.pack()

def helloCallBack():
   print ("Below is the output from the shell script in terminal")
   subprocess.call(['./date.sh inputValue']) #shell=True)


buttonCommit=Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Commit", 
                    command= helloCallBack) # retrieve_input())
#command=lambda: retrieve_input() >>> just means do this when i press the button
buttonCommit.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: It has to be like this `subprocess.call(['./date.sh %s' %inputValue], shell=True)` and also `inputValue` is an undefined variable for python you need to make it global or use one function instead of two.

Comment: Thank You so much. It worked!!!

Comment: A followup question... I want to make a gui to execute shell scripts with arguments (With the above help, I was able to test one such example). However, I want to create several such units (i,e: text box for input, and a button to click to execute the shells script with the arguments provided). I am having a problem in laying them out on the main tkinter screen. Any help appreciated... I reused the same piece of code as shown below but the gui is not pretty and also, it only executed the first script for the second script it gives Invalud Value error....

Comment: `from tkinter import *
import subprocess

root=Tk()
root2=Tk()
textBox=Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.pack()
textBox2=Text(root2, height=2, width=10)
textBox2.pack()

def helloCallBack():
   print ("Below is the output from the shell script in terminal")
   inputValue=textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
   print(inputValue)
   subprocess.call(['/u01/app/allscr/scripts/c %s' %inputValue] ,shell=True)
buttonCommit=Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Company Details", command= helloCallBack)
buttonCommit.pack()
############`

Comment: `def helloCallBack2():
   print ("Below is the output from the shell script in terminal")
   inputValue=textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
   print(inputValue)
   subprocess.call(['/u01/app/allscr/scripts/top20 %s' %inputValue] ,shell=True)


buttonCommit=Button(root2, height=5, width=20, text="Top20", command= helloCallBack2)
mainloop()`

Comment: Gee, this is not how to ask follow up questions. You should ask another question referencing to your previous question. Also avoid putting large block of code in comments.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to link a question to another, also, I don't know how to paste code... the window to paste code is not showing up when I type, but I can see it in others' postings. .. I read the "Learn more about comments..." it did not help much... any suggestions appreciated and I will follow through

Comment: I manage to run your code and it has no issues also I'm a bit confused on what types of commands you want to execute to the console and what do you mean by *"having a problem in laying them out on the main tkinter screen"*.

Comment: I am looking to build something like this...A simple GUI to avoid me from typing
the various scripts and arguments I pass to them over and over... instead just click a button..to
execute the script I want....

<button> <textbox1> <textbox2> 
when button is clicked it will execute a shell script with textbox1 and textbo2 
as arguments to script

<button> 
No arguments, just run script2

<button3> <textbox1>
will execute script3 with terxtbox1 value as argument 

etc..etc..

I am having problem with laying them out in that order on the canvas...